# zkteco RFID Id reader through PHP zklibrary

Tags: php, sockets, rfid

I am currently working on a project with Park Automation using attendance devices connected on LAN and I own the model K40 of ZKTeco company. Unfortunately, the device isn't implemented with a web server, so the only way to interact is using the TCP Port 4370.

The project is custom, written in PHP and I have used the carlosang2's library from GitHub (https://github.com/carlosang2/ZKLibrary) to interact with the devices. So far so good, everything works great, except the SetUser functionality. I can set a new user with id, name, password, role from my app to the device but I can't set the RFID of the card

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: did'nt found any solution.

Comment: Just I found the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Add an additional line to work with your Cardno,

```
$cardno = hex2bin(Util::reverseHex(dechex("1254107"))); //add this line

$command_string = $byte1.$byte2.chr($role).str_pad($password, 8, chr(0)).str_pad($name, 24, chr(0)).str_pad($cardno, 4, chr(0)).str_pad(chr(1), 9, chr(0)).str_pad($userid, 8, chr(0)).str_repeat(chr(0),16);
```

N.B. I am using this https://github.com/vodvud/php_zklib library. But I have to add the additional line in set() function. Its located in zklib->scr->User.php